# windows 7 change default behavior from sleep to hibernate

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

I'm running Windows 7 Pro with an Intel 520 SSD. The drive is encrypted and that's a great security feature: no HD password on boot-up = good luck crack a 256-bit encrypted SSD.

I set the default action to hibernate when I press the power button so that when the computer wakes up, it asks for the HD password. However, if the OS goes in Sleep mode, the HD password is not required when the computer awakes again. The problem is that if the computer goes idle for a few minutes, it goes to sleep instead of hibernate. I looked around but couldn't find a way to change this behavior; seem the hibernate option isn't part of the options!

**After X minutes, how do I make the computer Hibernate instead of Sleep?**

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click "change advanced power settings" at the bottom of that screen. there should be an option there.